# How do I make google maps pins open and close info windows while using ejs

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, ejs

I'm trying to load location information as well as other data and display it for each pin. I'm trying to make it so:

- only one info window is showing at once.
- each marker opens their info window on click.
- any other info windows will close if a new one is opened.

Here is my code. Right now it causes all of the info windows to open simultaneously and anonymously. All of the info windows stay closed once closed.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(43.083849,-77.675075),
            zoom:16,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);



        function addMarkers(map, loc, title, hour, name) {

            new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<div class='info'><br><h3 class='infotitle'>" + title + "</h3><br>" +
                "<p class='infodesc'>For " + hour + " hours</p><br>" +
                "<p>Posted by: " + name + "</p></div>"

            }).open(map, new google.maps.Marker({
                position: loc,
                label: '',
                map: map,
                title: 'Place1'
            }));

        }
        <% for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++) { %>
            addMarkers(map, {lat: <%= lats[i] %>, lng: <%= longs[i] %>}, "<%= titles[i] %>", "<%= parseFloat(hours[i]).toFixed(1) %>", "<%= names[i] %>"  );
        <% } %>
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
function addMarkers(map, loc, title, hour, name) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: loc,
       label: '',
       map: map,
       title: 'Place1'
    })
    var content = "<div class='info'><br><h3 class='infotitle'>" + title + "</h3><br>" +
            "<p class='infodesc'>For " + hour + " hours</p><br>" +
            "<p>Posted by: " + name + "</p></div>";
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
       infoWindow.setContent(content);
       infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });   
}
```

Comment: It's not loading any data. There's a for loop inside the ejs that loops through the addMarkers function.

Comment: Oh, there was a typo. Just noticed. maps.Marker instead of maker. Nice! It works! I didn't know you can reset the content of an info window. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, It works great! Thanks. I'd upvote, but not enough rep. :(